# My text won't center itself, no matter what I try

Tags: html, css

No matter what I try, nothing I've seen on stackoverflow or even youtube will work. This is my current html:

(The text I'm talking about is the one with the about-me class, with the text "A bit more about me.")

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <title id="ltitle">Cocolennon's Dev Stuff</title>
        <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.png">
        <meta name="description" content="I'm a 15 year old software and web developer from France.">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <meta http-equiv='cache-control' content='no-cache'> 
        <meta http-equiv='expires' content='0'> 
        <meta http-equiv='pragma' content='no-cache'>
        <meta content="#A020F0" data-react-helmet="true" name="theme-color">
        <meta content="https://www.cocolennon.xyz/favicon.png" property="og:image" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <header class="header">
            <a href="#" class="logo">Cocolennon</a>
            <nav class="navbar">
                <a href="#about-me">About Me</a>
                <!--
                <a href="#">Projects</a>
                <a href="#">Contact</a>
                -->
                <a href="#" onclick="setLang('en')">English</a>
                <a href="#" onclick="setLang('fr')">Français</a>
            </nav>
        </header>
        <h1 class="name">
            <span id="lname">Sup, my name's </span>
            <span style="color:darkorchid" id="lcoco">Cocolennon</span>
            <span class="aka" id="laka"> aka Coco</span>
        </h1>
        <h1 class="desc">
            <span id="lshort">I'm a 15 year old software and web developer from </span>
            <span style="color:blue" id="lfr">Fr</span><span id="lan">an</span><span style="color:red" id="lce">ce</span>.
        </h1>
        <div class="hsocials">
            <nav class="socials">
                <a href="https://www.youtube.com/@cocolennon_" target="_blank">
                    <button class="button" style="background-image: url(images/svgs/youtube.svg);"></button>
                </a>
                <a href="https://discord.gg/yqG4u2JnrV" target="_blank">
                    <button class="button" style="background-image: url(images/svgs/discord.svg);"></button>
                </a>
                <a href="https://github.com/Cocolennon" target="_blank">
                    <button class="button" style="background-image: url(images/svgs/github.svg);"></button>
                </a>
                <a href="https://paypal.me/Cocolennon" target="_blank">
                    <button class="button" style="background-image: url(images/svgs/paypal.svg);"></button>
                </a>
                <a href="https://steamcommunity.com/id/Cocolennon/" target="_blank">
                    <button class="button" style="background-image: url(images/svgs/steam.svg);"></button>
                </a>
                <a href="https://namemc.com/profile/CCocolennon.1" target="_blank">
                    <button class="button" style="background-image: url(images/svgs/namemc.svg);"></button>
                </a>
                <a href="https://e-z.bio/cocolennon" target="_blank">
                    <button class="button" style="background-image: url(images/svgs/ezhost.svg);"></button>
                </a>
                <a href="https://www.twitch.tv/cocolennon_" target="_blank">
                    <button class="button" style="background-image: url(images/svgs/twitch.svg);"></button>
                </a>
                <a href="mailto:contact@cocolennon.xyz" target="_blank">
                    <button class="button" style="background-image: url(images/svgs/gmail.svg);"></button>
                </a>
            </nav>
        </div>
        <h1 class="about-me">A bit more about me.</h1>
        <script src="script.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

And here is my current css:

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Kanit:wght@500&display=swap');

* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-family: 'Kanit', sans-serif;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
}

html {
    min-height: 100vh;
}

body {
    background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(36,37,34,0.9),rgba(36,37,34,0.9)), url('images/grid.png');
}

.header {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 20px 100px;
    background:#46354e;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    z-index: 100;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 30px;
}

.logo {
    font-size: 32px;
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight: bolder;
}

.navbar a {
    position: relative;
    font-size: 18px;
    color: #fff;
    font-weight: lighter;
    text-decoration: none;
    margin-left: 3vw;
    transition: .3s;
}

.navbar a:hover {
    color: darkorchid;
}

.navbar a::before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    left: 50%;
    width: 0;
    height: 2px;
    background: #fff;
    transition: .3s;
}

.navbar a:hover::before {
    width: 100%;
    left: 0;
    background: darkorchid;
}

.name {
    position: absolute;
    top: 30%;
    left: 10%;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 44px;
}

.aka {
    color: rgb(94, 94, 94);
    font-size: 22px;
    font-style: italic;
}

.desc {
    position: absolute;
    top: 30%;
    left: 10%;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 44px;
    font-size: 28px;
    font-weight: lighter;
    top: 40%;
}

.hsocials {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 9.2%;
    width: 70%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
}

.socials a {
    position: relative;
    font-size: 18px;
    color: #fff;
    font-weight: lighter;
    text-decoration: none;
    margin-left: 10px;
    transition: .3s;
}

.button {
    position: relative;
    background-color: #525050;
    border: none;
    color: white;
    padding: 25px;
    font-size: 16px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    background-size: 70%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position-x: center;
    background-position-y: center;
    transition: 0.3s;
}

.button:hover {
    background-color: #949191;
    border-radius: 30%;
}

.about-me {
    position: absolute;
    top: 110%;
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
}
```

I've tried stuff like using `display: flex` and `justify-content: center` but that didn't work aswell.
Using `margin-left: auto` and `margin-right: auto` didn't work either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to do it with no trouble, meaning there is other CSS that is keeping text-align from centering it. I added a couple more style rules to hopefully override the other CSS when you add it to your real project. You may want to try !mportant directives, too.

Edit: rereading your post, is `text-align: center` perhaps what you are looking for? That would make sense because you're trying to center text inside a 100% wide div. Not center the div itself in the page.

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Kanit:wght@500&display=swap');
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: 'Kanit', sans-serif;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}

html {
  min-height: 100vh;
}

body {
  background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(36, 37, 34, 0.9), rgba(36, 37, 34, 0.9)), url('images/grid.png');
}

.header {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 20px 100px;
  background: #46354e;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  z-index: 100;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 30px;
}

.about-me
{
    text-align: center;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<header class="header">
  <a href="#" class="logo">Cocolennon</a>
  <nav class="navbar">
    <a href="#about-me">About Me</a>
    <!--
                <a href="#">Projects</a>
                <a href="#">Contact</a>
                -->
    <a href="#" onclick="setLang('en')">English</a>
    <a href="#" onclick="setLang('fr')">Français</a>
  </nav>
</header>
<h1 class="name">
  <span id="lname">Sup, my name's </span>
  <span style="color:darkorchid" id="lcoco">Cocolennon</span>
  <span class="aka" id="laka"> aka Coco</span>
</h1>
<h1 class="desc">
  <span id="lshort">I'm a 15 year old software and web developer from </span>
  <span style="color:blue" id="lfr">Fr</span><span id="lan">an</span><span style="color:red" id="lce">ce</span>.
</h1>
<div class="hsocials">
  <nav class="socials">
    <a href="https://www.youtube.com/@cocolennon_" target="_blank">
      <button class="button" style="background-image: url(images/svgs/youtube.svg);"></button>
    </a>
    <a href="https://discord.gg/yqG4u2JnrV" target="_blank">
      <button class="button" style="background-image: url(images/svgs/discord.svg);"></button>
    </a>
    <a href="https://github.com/Cocolennon" target="_blank">
      <button class="button" style="background-image: url(images/svgs/github.svg);"></button>
    </a>
    <a href="https://paypal.me/Cocolennon" target="_blank">
      <button class="button" style="background-image: url(images/svgs/paypal.svg);"></button>
    </a>
    <a href="https://steamcommunity.com/id/Cocolennon/" target="_blank">
      <button class="button" style="background-image: url(images/svgs/steam.svg);"></button>
    </a>
    <a href="https://namemc.com/profile/CCocolennon.1" target="_blank">
      <button class="button" style="background-image: url(images/svgs/namemc.svg);"></button>
    </a>
    <a href="https://e-z.bio/cocolennon" target="_blank">
      <button class="button" style="background-image: url(images/svgs/ezhost.svg);"></button>
    </a>
    <a href="https://www.twitch.tv/cocolennon_" target="_blank">
      <button class="button" style="background-image: url(images/svgs/twitch.svg);"></button>
    </a>
    <a href="mailto:contact@cocolennon.xyz" target="_blank">
      <button class="button" style="background-image: url(images/svgs/gmail.svg);"></button>
    </a>
  </nav>
</div>
<h1 class="about-me">A bit more about me.</h1>
```

Comment: You, my sir, are a real life-saver. (The width rule fixed it)